Warm up time before tuning wind instruments
I have read that the air temperature in a wind instrument affects its pitch to a noticeable extent (see for example here and here). A temperature change of 5°C can result in a difference of 3 to 4 Hz, which would be clearly audible if played against another instrument tuned to the pitch agreed upon in our wind orchestra.
The first link also states that wind players blow warm air through their instruments before tuning/playing, warming up the instrument and also increasing air humidity. The air coming out from the lungs has a temperature of over 30°C (see https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1748-1716.1925.tb00831.x), so with a room temperature of around 20°C, the result would be a big difference in pitch (6+ Hz) that would make all tuning irrelevant (assuming the instrument were to be tuned completely "cold", which is admittedly not possible because the tuning itself would warm the air in the instrument up).
Are these considerations correct? I have not found information online answering that question.
How or for how long should players of different wind instruments (flute, horn, tuba, …) warm up or play their instruments before tuning them, in order to ensure that the instruments do not go out of tune after some time of playing?
I am interested in some best practices from experience for dealing with this issue, not necessarily an answer which is considering all possible factors.

The answer may also depend on the quality of the instrument, but I find that after 5-10 mins of playing, then tuning, all will stay in tune for the rest of the gig. A seasoned player  will always be aware of their tuning, and compensate if and when necessary during a performance.

Yes, this matters. Keep in mind that most instruments allow for some control of intonation, so even when the instrument goes out of tune you can compensate. Some wind player actually keep their instruments on their bodies (e.g. inside of their sleeves) to keep them warm.

In addition to the other answers: the only instruments you are likely to bring up to the temperature of your breath are tiny, for instance a garklein recorder (an octave higher than a soprano).  That's because, assuming the outside temperature is lower than that of your breath, instruments radiate heat, and the thermal mass of your breath simply doesn't have enough energy or conductivity to override that completely.

Of course the length of time will depend on how cold it was to start out with, too! There's a difference between a summer's day of 32C (no warmup needed?) and a crisp Autumn evening of 5C!

There are too many factors for this question to have a definitive, specific answer. In practice, near all musicians, including wind players, retune their instruments as needed during performance to account for changes in tuning that occur.
Here are some examples of variables that impact on the question of how and how long to tune before playing:

As mentioned, room temperature (or, for an outdoor setting, air temperature).
The time the instrument been in its setting before tuning.
Whether the instrument is warmer or colder that the setting and by how much.
The material construction of the instrument.

And some examples of variables affects how and how long to re-tune during a performance:

Changes in ambient temperature.
How much the instrument is played during the performance. (E.g., in some orchestral pieces, the trumpets might only play a few notes every minute or two, while in others, they may play nearly continually through the piece.)
Related to the above, the type of ensemble. (E.g., trumpets will play more in a brass quintet than in a baroque orchestra.)
In an ensemble, the rate at which other instruments go out of tune in relation to the instrument being tuned.

These lists are hardly exhaustive — they're just intended to suggest the complexity of the problem.

From experience, not very long.  Perhaps a minute?  That's indoors, where the temperature differential will be moderate.  And anyway, the pitch is going to be the same as it was yesterday.  'Tuning up' is mostly a confirmation, you might be surprised how rarely we actually need to move the tuning slides.
Outdoors, it's different.
In cold weather  wind instruments may never really stabilize their tuning.  We do the best we can!
